# How To show The YouTube Video Data in templates from Playlist's many to many field in Django, such as video name and video url

Tags: python, django

How can I display the video details using the many to many field in Django, what should be the syntax of the templates and views to fetch the all the videos of a playlist.

**--Models.py--**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Youtube_Video(models.Model):
    video_url = models.TextField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
    video_name = models.CharField(max_length=200 ,default="", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.video_name
    

class Playlist(models.Model):
    image_Url = models.TextField()
    playlist_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    playlist_Desc = models.TextField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    video = models.ManyToManyField(Youtube_Video, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.playlist_Name
```

**--Views.py--**

```
def videoItem(request, slug):
    playlist = Playlist.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    
    context = {
        'playlist': playlist,
    }

    return  render(request, "Home/videoItem.html", context)
```

--Templates

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Video{% endblock title %}
{% block body %}
<section id="videoItem">
    
</section>
<section>
    <h1>{{playlist.video.video_name}}</h1>
</section>
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to get many to many relationships.

---

```
<section>
    <h1>
        {% for vid in playlist.video.all %}
           {{ vid.video_name }}
        {% endfor %}
    </h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Playlist` instance can have many `Video` instances related to it, so you cannot directly access a video like this:

```
playlist.video.video_name
```

You can grab the videos associated with the playlist in the view and include them into context:

```py
def videoItem(request, slug):
    playlist = Playlist.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    videos = playlist.video.all()

    context = {
        'playlist': playlist,
        'videos': videos,
    }

    return  render(request, "Home/videoItem.html", context)
```

And then, loop through the `videos` and paste the information in the template:

```
<section>
    {% for video in videos %}
        <h1>{{ video.video_name }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```